# 1GB single DDR3 Chip for ZYNQ(XC7Z020-2CLG400I), is it possible?

Tags: pcb, fpga, xilinx, ddr3, zynq

I'm putting together a PCB and I want to use single 8Gb (512*16) DDR3 chip (MT41K512M16HA) but the DDR3 address bank is less than the DDR3  chip.

Is it possible to use single 8Gb chip for this IC?

Comment: XC7A50T is an Artix-7 FPGA, not a Zynq part. Zynq parts all have a "Z" as the fourth character, e.g. "XC7Z035".

Comment: sorry the part is XC7Z020-2CLG400I

Comment: see the parallela board they use a single ddr3 ic MT41K256M32SLD-125:E